# Setting custom file format class in mapreduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I extended some `FileInputFormat` by `XMLFileInputFormat`. The problem is that when I set this class on my `job`

```
job.setInputFormatClass(XMLFileInputFormat.class);
```

I get some error telling it expects this class to extend `or.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat` (but I checked that `FileInputFormat` implements `InputFormat`)

this class is set this way

```
public class XMLFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {

    @Override
    protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename) {
        return false; }

    @Override
    public RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> getRecordReader(
            InputSplit split, JobConf job, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        return new XMLFileRecordReader((FileSplit) split, job);
    }
}
```

How can I set correctly my `InputFormat` ?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the package structure in import statement. It should be 
org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileInputFormat.

You could have imported:
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat